# How can be written wp.element.createElement('img' into a registerBlockType?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, image, plugins, gutenberg-blocks

I am looking for a solution to this question about WordPress Blocks.
I have a plugin that create a brand new block of an img tag.
I would know how to display it in the wp.blocks.registerBlockType function.
Thanks in advice!

In the code of the js file I have put this for the result part:

```
save: function(props) {
return wp.element.createElement(
'img', {src: "https://api.nasa.gov/assets/img/general/apod.jpg"}
);
}
```

It's not correct. WordPress display the Attempt Recovery message.
What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with it!

The `wp.blocks.registerBlockType` needs title, icon, category, attributes and an edit function before the save function.

The correct code is here:

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('brad/border-box', {
    title: 'Test Image Block',
    icon: 'marker',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        content: {type: 'string'},
        color: {type: 'string'}
    },
 
    edit: function(props) {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            React.createElement("h3",null,"Test Image Block")
        );
    },

    save: function(props) {
      return wp.element.createElement(
        'img', 
        {src: "https://api.nasa.gov/assets/img/general/apod.jpg"}
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes of course. The wp.blocks.registerBlockType needs title, icon, category, attributes and an edit function before the save function.

Comment: I just added the explaination in your answer, thanks :)